# Extensibility of "hen"/"cock"

Tags: usage, vocabulary

As we all know from Xanth, a female egret is an egress. Also (even in German), ducks and geese have their own gender names. I [googled around a bit](https://termcoord.eu/2018/02/male-and-female-animal-names/) and concluded that the usage is random, to say the least: Lobsters and salmons are birds, as it seems, but crocodiles cattle. (The dragoness threatened to turn me into a pile of ash if I open my mouth.)

Is there any logic behind this except "some special names from hunting, otherwise memorize and shut up"? My instinct would have dictated hen/cock for "all birds - except ducks and geese (and possibly swans) -, all dinos, and maybe reptiles too".

Comment: "We all"? I've never even heard of Xanth.

Comment: lobsters and salmon, no s.

Comment: Those words are not about hunting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use is derived from the animals that humans have (or rather had) regular interactions with, and which the sex matters (to the human)

So sex of a domestic animal matters, and there are names for the sexes of most farm animals.  That includes chickens, ducks and geese.  But chickens are the most common farm bird.

For other animals the naming is by analogy with the farm animals. Crocodiles are big and may be aggressive, so the analogy is with cattle, and we say "bull crocodile". For most birds the analogy is with chickens.

For salmon you use "bucks" and "hens", that one is mixed, but is probably due to the way that male salmon become brightly coloured, but the females don't (like many birds).  Lobsters sexes are not particularly named. And this is the case for most wild animals. There are no special names in common use for male or female lizards, or cockroaches, fish or worms.  If necessary you say "a male lizard".

For a learner: don't worry about the sex names of wild animals, unless you have a particularly close interaction with them.  You don't need to memorise long lists of sex-based names of animals.  You should learn (at B2 to C level) the names of the farm animals, "hen/rooster (or cock, but this one causes sniggers)",  "cow/bull", "mare/stallion".  You should know these because they are often used in metaphor, and you should be aware of the nature of the insult associated with them.

I assume the "egress" thing is a joke.

Comment: At our local City Farm I heard a thirtyish mother tell her daughter that a cockerel was a 'man chicken'.

Comment: It used to be common to use 'cock' and 'hen' to distinguish the sexes of, for instance, garden birds, but naturalists now say 'male' and 'female'. (Though I believe the slang use of 'cock' is old, it's only comparatively recently that we have become coy of using it for a male chicken.)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Wikipedia: "Rooster and cock are terms for adult male birds, and a younger male may be called a cockerel". So, she was right to say that *to a child*.

Comment: +1 for explaining the logic behind the salmon. (Afterwards, it's kind of obvious.) And yes, "egress" is a typical Xanth plot-driving pun.

Comment: It used to be fairly well known that Phineas T Barnum's American Museum was so popular that people would spend the entire day there. This cut into profits, & the museum would be too full to squeeze another person in. Old P.T. put up signs that said "This Way to the Egress." Customers thought it was another exotic creature and followed the signs, which led to an exit door that locked behind them.

Comment: @Lambie - I felt she was displaying a kind of genteel Victorian prudishness, the kind that made people call a bull a 'gentleman cow' and, in the extreme, made people suggest that farmers put breeches or knickers on them (and stallions).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I thought that was covering "piano legs".

Comment: @Lambie - yes, another example. Apparently that was apocryphal. Possibly trousers for bulls, too, although the 'gentleman cow' is attested to in the 19th century UK and USA.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether it's formal or informal speech. If you were a zoologist speaking in a professional manner, you would probably know and use the correct name of a male or female animal. If you want to do that, you should just memorize them.

People in general probably don't know what the correct term is for the male and female versions or for the infant and adult versions of many animals. So in everyday speech, it would be quite common to say **female duck**, **male cow**, or **baby kangaroo** if you don't know the correct name.

Because **cock** is a slang term that refers to male genitalia, **rooster** would be more common to avoid the vulgar use. In some cases, however, **cock** is always used, for example, **cock fight**.